# run python tests with waf_unit_test

Tags: python, waf

I have an application written in c++ and tests for it. Partially written on c++ and partially on python.
With c++ tests everything is clear. How I can run python based tests in the same build phase?
The following code does not run my python file with tests.

```
def build(bld):
    bld(features="test", rule="touch ${SRC}", source="main.py")

    ## printing test results to output
    from waflib.Tools import waf_unit_test

    bld.add_post_fun(waf_unit_test.summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `test_scripts` feature:

```py
def build(bld):
    bld(features='test_scripts',
        rule='touch ${SRC}',
        test_scripts_source = 'main.py',
        test_scripts_template = 'python ${SCRIPT}',
        source='main.py')

     from waflib.Tools import waf_unit_test
     bld.add_post_fun(waf_unit_test.summary)
```